# I have designed only one method to a button, how to detect the action for multiple events in a single method

Tags: ios, uibutton

How can i declare a single button with single method along with multiple UIControlEvents?

Please help thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button1.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 60);
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}
```

Comment: If you want the method to be called for all touch events you can `UIControlEventAllTouchEvents`. Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The UIEvent that you get from UIButton doesn't give you any information about which UIControlEvent caused it. Either register separate methods for each event type (the recommended solution) or make your own subclass of UIControl and make it behave differently.

Internally, UIControl subclasses are basically using the  [sendActionsForControlEvents:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW1) method, which means they can choose to put anything they want as the parameter.

As for how to know, the simple answer is to have a separate method for each control event.